# linear transformation proof problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So question is :

For any $m\times n$ matrix $A$,let $T_A$ be the linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ deﬁned by
$T_A(x) = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices.

Prove that $\operatorname{im}(T_A) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(T_B)$ if and only if every column of $A$ is a linear combination of the
columns of $B$.

So far what I have done:

Given $\operatorname{im}(T_A)$ R.T.P: Every column of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns of $B$

Denote $A$ as  and $B$ as

Since any element in $\operatorname{im}(T_A)$ is of the form $Ax$ for some $x$

So by assumption: $\operatorname{im}(T_A)$, there exists some $y$  s.t. $Ax=By$

Since this holds for any $x$, first take $x=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$

Since $Ax=$ and there exists some $y$  s.t. $Ax=By$ if $b_{ij}=c_n*a_{ij}$

So Every column of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns of $B$

Assumption proved.

But I do not think the way how I prove that there exists some $y$ s.t. $Ax=By$ is right, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Note that  the lianiarly indipendent columuns of $T_B$ are a base for $Im (T_B)$ as the colums of $T_A$ for $Im (T_A)$. Then the equivalence is obvius.